# Sleep key stops working after some time

Tags: suspend, sleep

I've got a "Sleep" key on my keyboard that I use to suspend the system when I'm away from the computer for a longer time.

This works fine, at least for a while after I've turned the computer on. However, after some time, the Sleep key just stops working, and I've got to reboot the computer to make it work again.

Problem is, I don't know what to check. What kinds of things can change in a system to disrupt the operation of this key? And sometimes it takes longer than other times before it stops working; sometimes I can use the key for days on end; other times it won't even work once.
I can still always use `pm-suspend` manually to suspend the system, so it's not the system itself that has become corrupted, only the keyboard.

Anyone got any ideas on what to check, where to begin? I'm running Debian, by the way.

Comment: When you press the key, does anything appear in the system logs? Look for any file under `/var/log` that changes when you press the key.

Comment: I can try that. Of course it works fine now, so I'll have to wait until it breaks again.

Comment: I made copies of the files in the log directory, in particular the pm-suspend.log, so I can see if there's different info in there after it starts failing.